# CUSP function to generate a matrix with random values

Tags: cuda, cusp-library

I was wondering if CUSP library provides a function that creates a matrix with a specific number of columns, rows, and any random values?

I found poisson5pt function but it doesn't return back a matrix with the dimensions I specify!

Thanks in advance

Comment: `poisson5pt` is for generating a 5 point stencil approximation of the [Poisson equoation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_equation) on a regular grid. It has nothing to do with random numbers and the mxn argument is the dimensions of the *computational domain* not the resulting matrix.

Comment: I took it from https://github.com/pathscale/cusp-library/blob/master/performance/conversions/test.cu line 107 where it is supposedly used to generate an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the CUSP matrix gallery you will find [random.h](https://github.com/cusplibrary/cusplibrary/blob/master/cusp/gallery/random.h) which almost does what you want:

```
template <class MatrixType>
void random(size_t num_rows, size_t num_cols, size_t num_samples, MatrixType& output)
```

This will produce a  matrix of the dimensions you specify with the number of random locations you request filled with 1.

It would be trivial to modify that to use a random value rather than unity, although I don't understand why you would ever want such a matrix. It will not be guaranteed to have any of the properties you probably need in a test matrix if you have plans to use such a matrix in any linear algebra operations.

Comment: So this function doesn't allow filling the matrix with values other than 1, so is there any other functions that can do that (fill matrix with random values upon creation)?!

Comment: Not that I am aware of, and with good reason, as I mentioned in my answer. I gave you a link to the code. You need to change exactly *one line* to make it do what you want. Just make your own implementation with that one line changed.